# A member of a village of little people paints her door green and is exiled

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

..along with a couple of other misfits whom the council or somesuch feels are simply not appropriate people to be members of their village.  Of course the group of exiles spot invaders and are instrumental in their defeat.  It was a childrens novel I read in the seventies and would love to have my own children read.  There were simple line illustrations.  I seem to recall an embossed seal on the cover implying it was some kind of award winner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this might be [*The Gammage Cup*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gammage_Cup) (also published as *The Minnipins*) by Carol Kendall, a Newberry Honor book published in 1959.

(Does anyone else get the feeling that this question was asked here before?  I can't find anything by searching, but still...)

Comment: I was thinking it was this book too.